# Google Sheets: Automatic add rows in multiple sheets based on Master Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with multiple tabs. The first one is the Master Sheet where I have some basic location info. In the other sheets I'm transferring those basic info through "Importrange" so I have some columns dynamically changing and some that are static and the users are able to update. Although, if I add a row in between my data at the Master Sheet it will only change the dynamic columns (updated from importrange) but the rest columns won't change- which will mess with the updates.
**Is there any way/ script where I can add rows in the other sheets automatically when a row is added in the master one?**

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: When you are copying data from one tab to another within the same spreadsheet file, you should not be using `importrange()` but an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) or an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a *row misalignment issue*. See Lance's thorough [treatment of the issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649) and how it can be dealt with in some cases. It is a lengthy read, and too long to repeat here.

If you are simply trying to let each user to edit "their" data, you can also keep *all* the data in the master sheet and use [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to decide which rows to show at a time. This feature lets multiple simultaneous users sort, filter and edit a sheet without disturbing each other.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.